# Screen session terminates when program crashes

Tags: debian, gnu-screen, crash

I am running a program in a Screen session if the program crashes it restarts itself, but when the program crashes the screen session terminates.

I want the screen session to stay open so the program can restart itself. Is there any way to do that?

I am running Linux Debian 7 Wheezy

Answer (score 2):

Question is,  how bizarre does the program crash?  First two things that come to my mind:

- the program sends out with its last dying breath some strange control sequences that let `screen` also crash/terminate/think it is better to not let you see this.
- the program sends signals to its parent processes (`screen` or maybe an intermediate *shell*) that terminates them.

Next steps I would try:

1. How precisely is `screen` terminated?  Does it kill the whole `screen` process or only its own window (are parallel running screen commands still alive,  does the screen session gets detached)?
2. If you run the program from a shell,  can you *catch signals* coming from the program using *trap*?
3. Does it still terminate `screen` if you redirect *stdout* and *stderr* to a file (what does the file contain if it doesn't crash anymore — I'm curious).  Maybe you still can watch the program running using `tail -f`.
4. OK, circumvention won't give interesting insights,  but does the same problem exist when using `tmux` instead of `screen`?

---

Edit 1 (ad 1):
The crashing program can be either run directly from screen, e.g.

```
screen /usr/local/bin/your/crashing/program
```

or with a shell process inbetween (e.g. you start your screen window with your favorite shell,  then run the program like

```
screen
/usr/local/bin/your/crashing/program
```

or have a shell script that does the respawning with something like

```
bash -c 'while true ; do /usr/local/bin/your/crashing/program ; done'
```

You can tell from the output of `pstree` which processes are involved:

```
xterm(309)---bash(311)---screen(230)---screen(231)---bash(234)-+-less(323)
                                                               `-pstree(322)
```

In my case I have a started `screen` (230 and 231) from a `bash` (311) in a `xterm` (309) window with another `bash` (234), from which I have run `pstree | less` (322 and 323).

Screen terminates if the child process does.  This is normal behavior and not a crash.  So if your program is started directly in screen and crashes, screen also terminates.  If you have your program started by hand in a shell,  that shell should again present its prompt after the program has crashed.  If the screen window closes in this case,  something is in fact weird.

It would be helpful to know a little bit the roundabout, e.g. how you start and respawn your program.

Comment: So screen does not crash when a program in screen crashes? When I checked the server it suddenly had 2 screens running the same program (this happened after a crash). Anyway when I use a restart command on the program screen says: Screen is terminating.

Comment: @Zero - no Screen shouldn't ever crash.

Comment: very helpful answer thanks ua2b. if anyone else comes across this, I was using `exit` instead of `return` inside a custom function in my `.bashrc` which was causing the screen window to close